# jQuery click or touchstart event is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, onclick, jquery-events

I am using [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) to get peoples phone code and country. When they select the flag and code I have some jQuery with gets the country and code separately and populates hidden fields...

Here is the entire object which handles these operations:

```
var telInput = {
    init: function(){
        this.setTelInput();
        this.cacheDOM();
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDOM: function(){
        this.$countryCode = $('input[name=country_code]');
        this.$countryName = $('input[name=country_name]');
        this.$country     = $('.country');
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        this.$country.on('click', this.getTelInput.bind(this));
    },
    setTelInput: function(){
        $('input[name=phone]').intlTelInput({
            preferredCountries: [
                'gb'
            ],
        });
    },
    getTelInput: function(e){
        var el          = $(e.target).closest('.country');
        var countryCode = el.attr('data-dial-code');
        var countryName = el.find('.country-name').text();
        this.$countryCode.val(countryCode);
        this.$countryName.val(countryName);
    },
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is the click event in the `bindEvents` method... the phone picker works but the `onclick` event is not being triggered to populate my hidden fields.

Comment: Do you call the `cacheDOM ` method after the DOM has been rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you cache the DOM after it has been rendered. Here's a simplified example.

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40dqnrzz/2/)

```
var telInput = {
  init: function(){
    this.cacheDOM();
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  cacheDOM: function() {
    this.$country = $('.country');
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    this.$country.on('click', function() {
      // console.log('Triggered');
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  telInput.init();
});
```

---

Also, plugin's event [`countrychange`](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#events) could be useful in your case.

```
$("#country-select-element").on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {
    // do something with countryData
});
```

I would also suggest you to have a look at the [public methods](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#public-methods). It has some useful methods that you could use to achieve the same result.